# Create a grouped table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing a song book and want an artist directory/index, i.e. a mapping from artist to the pages in the song book where the song of that artist occurs.

Here's a a minimal working example of what I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

% this is what I want to automatically generate
Artist Directory

AC/DC  3,4,6

Deep Purple 5,6,7
\newpage

\section{Back in Black - AC/DC}
\label{AC/DC}
Test
\newpage

\section{Highway to Hell - AC/DC}
\label{AC/DC}
Test
\newpage

\section{Highway Star - Deep Purple}
\label{Deep Purple}
Test
\newpage

\section{Perfect Stranger - Deep Purple}
\label{Deep Purple}
Test
\newpage

\section{Smoke On the Water - Deep Purple}
\label{Deep Purple}
Test
\newpage

\section{The Honey Roll - AC/DC}
\label{AC/DC}
Test
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Obviously using the labels is not the way to go, since these have to be unique.

Comment: `glossaries` you want. And you forgot `Hells Bells` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are packages that typeset songs already, but here is short way to get the information with a glossary:

```
\newglossaryentry{bandnameabbrev}{type=rockgroups,name={Real Bandname},description={optionally empty}}*
```

will define a band in the glossary, `\gls*{ac/dc}` will use `Real Bandname` and leaves information that this band has been used on page in the glossary.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[nomain,nopostdot]{glossaries}


\newglossary{rockgroups}{rki}{rko}{Artist Directory}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{ac/dc}{
  type=rockgroups,
  name={AC/DC},
  description={}}

\newglossaryentry{deeppurple}{
  type=rockgroups,
  name={Deep Purple},
  description={}
}

\newcommand{\songtext}[3]{\
  \section{#1 - \gls*{#2}}%

  #3%
  \clearpage
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\printglossaries

\clearpage

\songtext{Back in Black}{ac/dc}{\blindtext}


\songtext{Highway to Hell}{ac/dc}{\blindtext[2]}

\songtext{Highway Star}{deeppurple}{\blindtext[2]}

\songtext{Perfect Stranger}{deeppurple}{\blindtext[2]}

\songtext{Smoke on the Water}{deeppurple}{\blindtext[2]}

\songtext{The Honey Roll}{ac/dc}{\blindtext}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Addendum: The leadsheets library I am using currently doesn't support indexing.

Comment: @anopheles: You're welcome. You can extend the glossaries yourself, there are many useful options in the package `glossaries` etc.